# SonarQube analysis for java play framework

Tags: playframework, sonarqube, sonarlint-intellij

how to use sonarqube for code written in java play framework? sonarlint plugin is working but binding sonarqube server is not working. project not bound is showing when trying to updtate.

tried sonarlint binding to sonarQube and also tried running using command prompt both shows error.

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
> org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell SonarQube where to find the compiled classed of the Play project which by default it's here:

```
sonar.java.binaries=target/scala-2.10/classes
```